# SSH ChrootDirectory Fails on login error: /dev/pts/2: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I've created a user in Ubuntu and given them password auth access so they can login with ssh but i want to restrict their usage to a custom home folder located in:

```
/var/www/daniel (is a root folder with correct permissions)
/var/www/daniel/home (which is owned by daniel:daniel and 755 permissions)
```

In

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config (i've enabled internal sftp)

Match User daniel
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  AllowTCPForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory %h
  X11Forwarding no
```

restarted ssh service

then when i try to log in, i can see in the

```
auth.log
```

successful user login but it then kills the session based on this error

```
Accepted password for daniel ssh2
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user daniel by (uid=0)
systemd-logind[508]: New session 63 of user daniel.
pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user daniel by (uid=0)
error: /dev/pts/2: No such file or directory
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user daniel
Session 63 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

i've executed the below from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160461/chroot-gone-wrong-cant-ssh-with-user:

```
mount --bind /dev /var/daniel/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /var/daniel/dev/pts
```

the error appears to be gone but it logs me straight out after auth

```
Accepted password for daniel
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user daniel by (uid=0)
systemd-logind[508]: New session 130 of user daniel.
systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user daniel by (uid=0)
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user daniel
systemd-logind[508]: Session 130 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/passwd`.

Normally the users home directory is `/home/USER` and the variable `%h` maps to the file path `/home/daniel` in that case.

Also you need to provide a path to `/bin/bash` or similar shell inside the chroot  if the user should be able to login via SSH.

Comment: cat etc/passwd for that user shows me daniel:x:1001:1002::/var/www/daniel:/bin/sh this seems ok?

Comment: Running ls -la shows me:
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 Nov  9 11:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   root   4096 Nov  8 20:21 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 daniel daniel  220 Apr  9  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 daniel daniel 3771 Jul 12  2019 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 17 root   root   3900 Nov  9 10:32 dev (mounted folder)
drwxr-xr-x  3 daniel daniel 4096 Nov  8 21:52 home
-rw-r--r--  1 daniel daniel  807 Apr 18  2022 .profile

shouldn't bash profile be there? not sure if i am doing this right

Comment: All filenames starting with "." like `.profile` are autogenerated. Bash profile isn't there, since you don't use bash shell for the user daniel as stated in your passwd file. You are using `ash` shell instead which has a slightly different syntax when it comes to shell scripting. But in a nutshell you need to copy `/bin` to a subfolder inside the chroot or else can't do stuff like `mv`,`cp`, `rm` inside the chroot because there are no visible path to those commands.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to add the bash shell to that directory please? it says bin/sh  when i cat the passwd file? i don't see ash? not sure if i am missing something?

Comment: Just replace `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash` in passwd file. :-)

Comment: thank you will try now :)

Comment: would mount --bind /bin /var/daniel/bin be correct like i did with the /dev & /dev/pts or just copy folder over? i've change to daniel:x:1001:1002::/var/www/daniel:/bin/bash too.

Comment: Never tried it, but I expect as much.

Comment: So i've mounted the /bin folder and can access that in the chroot user folder. but even before i did this and after i did it.  see the logs:

Accepted password for daniel ssh2
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user daniel by (uid=0)
New session 259 of user daniel.
pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user daniel by (uid=0)
sshd[11812]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user daniel
Session 259 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.

it just logs me auto on putty directly after authentication

Comment: if i turn on ChrootDirectory %h it logs in then logs out, if i disable, it logs in. should the chroot point to the root owned /var/www/daniel folder or the daniel owned folder of /var/www/daniel/home ? if i change the chroot to /var/www/daniel/home i get bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/www/daniel/home"

Answer (score 0):

Been using this for years on Ubuntu.

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Match Group sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    X11Forwarding no
```

The chroot directory must be root owned and not have write access for the user. Internal directories can be writable. This was done to avoid having home files that can change the library preloading. But you will get errors in auth.log if this is wrong.

Also you have to limit your client to sftp and not open a normal ssh session with terminal.